# Windows inside markers for angular-google-maps only work when set visible from the start

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm using angular-google-maps and had a list of markers that should all have infowindows. This is my code so far:

```
$scope.markers = [
                {id: 1,
                 coords: {latitude: 45, longitude: -73},
                 clk:function(){showWindow = true; $scope.$apply();},
                 showWindow: false,
                 closeClick:function(){ showWindow = false; }
                },
                [More identically structured markers]
            ];
```

and in the markup:

```
<google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" ng-show="true" draggable="true" control="map.control">            
         <markers models="markers" coords="'coords'" click="'clk'" doRebuildAll="true">
             <windows show="'showWindow'" closeClick="'closeClick'" options="map.wndoptions">
                <div >
                    Marker
                    <input type="button" value="U" ng-click="$parent.moveMarkerUp()"></input>
                    <input type="button" value="D" ng-click="$parent.moveMarkerDown()"></input>
                    <input type="button" value="L" ng-click="$parent.moveMarkerLeft()"></input>
                    <input type="button" value="R" ng-click="$parent.moveMarkerRight()"></input>
                </div>
         </windows>
         </markers>
    </google-map>
```

When I set `showWindow` to true from the start, all the infowindows open and they behave as they should, I can close and open them again. I don't want them to all be visible from the start though, so I set `showWindow` to false, but now when I click the markers, nothing happens. The function is called an `showWindow` is updated, but no windows are shown.

Comment: don't you need $scope.$apply() on your closeClick function too?

Comment: ever get a chance to figure this out?